# How to handle thrid parameter of function "done" in passport.js?

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-local

I saw the example code at http://passportjs.org/docs that we can pass third parameter for done function of passport

Code:

```
var passport = require('passport')
  , LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
      }
      if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
      }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));
```

In this case they are passing { message: 'Incorrect username.' }.

My question is how to handle this third parameter.

EDIT:
This is my routing code:

```
app.post('/login', 
  passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
  });
```

I want to know how to use message that send from passport like

```
res.render('myjade', {'message': **THAT MESSAGE**})
```

something like this

Comment: how to handle it in what regard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs:

> Redirects are often combined with flash messages in order to display status information to the user.
>
> Setting the failureFlash option to true instructs Passport to flash an error message using the message given by the strategy's verify callback, if any.
>
> Note: Using flash messages requires a req.flash() function. Express 2.x provided this functionality, however it was removed from Express 3.x. Use of connect-flash middleware is recommended to provide this functionality when using Express 3.x.

So modify your call to authenticate to be:

```
passport.authenticate('local', {
  failureRedirect: '/login',
  failureFlash: true
}),
```

and then either use the `connect-flash` middleware or define your own middleware to provide the `req.flash()` function.